# How to executing (eval) Expression with "varchars,custom functions,numbers and dates"

Tags: java, eval, formula, varchar

What will be the correct way to eval the custom expression's that can contains operations, varchars, numbers, custom functions, dates.

At the beginning I am using 'Udo Klimaschewski' [Expression utility](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx/tree/master/src/com/udojava/evalex)

All is very well but this utility is not working with varchars, only with numbers. 
But formula what need to be executed can contains varchars too, preview : =((1=2) and ('abc'= 'abc'))

For date I done the tricky thing transform date expression to long and then compare.
Sample code from modified utility:

**eval()**

```
    public BigDecimal eval() {

    Stack<BigDecimal> stack = new Stack<BigDecimal>();

    for (String token : getRPN()) {
        mylog.pl("Reverse polish notation TOKEN : " + token + " RPN size: " + getRPN().size() );
        if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            BigDecimal v1 = stack.pop();
            BigDecimal v2 = stack.pop();
            stack.push(operators.get(token).eval(v2, v1));
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            stack.push(variables.get(token).round(mc));
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
            Function f = functions.get(token.toUpperCase());
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> p = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>(f.getNumParams());
            for (int i = 0; i < f.numParams; i++) {
                p.add(0, stack.pop());
            }
            BigDecimal fResult = f.eval(p);
            stack.push(fResult);
        } else if (isDate(token)) {
            Long date = null;
            try {
                date = SU.sdf.parse(token).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {/* IGNORE! */
            }
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(date, mc));
        } else {
//Here now is error because expresion is varchar not a number 
//java.lang.NumberFormatException
                stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
            }
        }
        return stack.pop().stripTrailingZeros();
    }
```

**Reverse notation**

```
    private List<String> getRPN() {
    if (rpn == null) {
        rpn = shuntingYard(this.expression);
    }
    return rpn;
}
```

**ShuntingYard**

```
private List<String> shuntingYard(String expression) {
    List<String> outputQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);

    String lastFunction = null;
    while (tokenizer.hasNext()) {
        String token = tokenizer.next();
        if (isNumber(token)) {
            outputQueue.add(token);                     
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            outputQueue.add(token);
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
            stack.push(token);
            lastFunction = token;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(token.charAt(0))) {
            if (BusinessStrategy.PREFIX_X.equals(Character.toString(token.charAt(0)))){
                //HERE can catch all varchar's prefix is added before this utility
                outputQueue.add(token);                    
            } else {
                stack.push(token);                    
            }
        } else if (",".equals(token)) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && !"(".equals(stack.peek())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ExpressionException("Parse error for function '"
                        + lastFunction + "'");
            }
        } else if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            Operator o1 = operators.get(token);
            String token2 = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.peek();
            while (operators.containsKey(token2)
                    && ((o1.isLeftAssoc() && o1.getPrecedence() <= operators
                            .get(token2).getPrecedence()) || (o1
                            .getPrecedence() < operators.get(token2)
                            .getPrecedence()))) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
                token2 = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.peek();
            }
            stack.push(token);
        } else if ("(".equals(token)) {
            stack.push(token);
        } else if (")".equals(token)) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && !"(".equals(stack.peek())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Mismatched parentheses");
            }
            stack.pop();
            if (!stack.isEmpty()
                    && functions.containsKey(stack.peek().toUpperCase())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        String element = stack.pop();
        if ("(".equals(element) || ")".equals(element)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Mismatched parentheses");
        }
        if (!operators.containsKey(element)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown operator or function: "
                    + element);
        }
        outputQueue.add(element);
    }
    return outputQueue;
}
```

Maybe someone already done something similar and can help with suggestion ? 
Thanks!

**Edit1**
I edited eval like this now I don't know what to do with custom functions :(

```
public Object eval() {

    Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>();

    for (String token : getRPN()) {
        mylog.pl("Reverse polish notation TOKEN : " + token + " RPN size: " + getRPN().size() );
        if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            Object v1 = stack.pop();
            Object v2 = stack.pop();
            stack.push(operators.get(token).eval(v2, v1));
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            stack.push(variables.get(token).round(mc));
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
           /* Function f = functions.get(token.toUpperCase());
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> p = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>(f.getNumParams());
            for (int i = 0; i < f.numParams; i++) {
                p.add(0, stack.pop());
            }
            BigDecimal fResult = f.eval(p);
            stack.push(fResult);*/
        } else if (isDate(token)) {
            Long date = null;
            try {
                date = SU.sdf.parse(token).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {/* IGNORE! */
            }
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(date, mc));
        } else {
            //stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
            if (BusinessStrategy.PREFIX_X.equals(Character.toString(token.charAt(0)))) {
                //Push the string without quotes.
                mylog.pl("VARCHAR PUSH");
                stack.push(token.substring(0, token.length()));
            } else {
                stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();//.stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

**Operators**
maybe are some way how normalize this code?

```
       addOperator(new Operator("=", 7, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(Object v1, Object v2) {
            if (v1.getClass() == v2.getClass()){
               if (v1 instanceof String){
                   String s1 = (String) v1;
                   String s2 = (String) v2;
                   return s1.equals(s2) == true ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
               } else if (v1 instanceof BigDecimal){
                   BigDecimal b1 = (BigDecimal) v1;
                   BigDecimal b2 = (BigDecimal) v2;
                   return b1.compareTo(b2) == 0 ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
               }
            } else {
                // TODO Throw something
                mylog.pl("Wrong types");
                return null;
            }
            //How to avoid this return ? 
            return null;
        }
    });
    addOperator(new Operator("==", 7, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(Object v1, Object v2) {
            return operators.get("=").eval(v1, v2);
        }
    });

    addOperator(new Operator("!=", 7, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(Object v1, Object v2) {
            if (v1.getClass() == v2.getClass()){
                if (v1 instanceof String){
                    String s1 = (String) v1;
                    String s2 = (String) v2;
                    return s1.equals(s2) == false ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
                } else if (v1 instanceof BigDecimal){
                    BigDecimal b1 = (BigDecimal) v1;
                    BigDecimal b2 = (BigDecimal) v2;
                    return b1.compareTo(b2) != 0 ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
                }
             } else {
                 // TODO Throw something
                 mylog.pl("Wrong types");
                 return null;
             }
             //How to avoid this return ? 
             return null;
        }
    });
    addOperator(new Operator("<>", 7, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(Object v1, Object v2) {
            return operators.get("!=").eval(v1, v2);
        }
    });
```

**And what to do with these operators?**
For varchars need only equal or not how to easy and normally rewrite these?

```
    addOperator(new Operator("<=", 10, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2) {
            return v1.compareTo(v2) <= 0 ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
    });

        addOperator(new Operator("and", 4, false) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal v1, BigDecimal v2) {
            boolean b1 = !v1.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            boolean b2 = !v2.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            return b1 && b2 ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
    });
```

**Custom function**

```
        addFunction(new Function("SalStrLeftX", 2) {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal eval(List<BigDecimal> parameters) {
            Object o = null;
            try {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.disnet.business.Functions");
                Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("SalStrLeftX", String.class, int.class);
                o = method.invoke (c.newInstance(), parameters.get(0).toPlainString(), parameters.get(1).intValueExact());
                System.out.println("Value from SalStrLeftX "+o);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //TODO for Varchar
            return SU.getBigDecimal(o);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try MVEL. - If you want to roll your own: basically you need a lexer and a parser for the expression grammar (you should define up front *before* starting anything). Parsing results in an AST (abstract syntax tree) and you can interpret/evaluate this structure (or generate some code and interpret that or ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need more than one type. You could introduce a new class Value, but Object will do.

```
public Object eval() {

Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<>();


    } else {
        if (token.matches("(?s)'.*'") {
            stack.push(token.substring(1, token.length() - 1);
        } else {
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
        }
    }
```

Push the string without quotes.

And then the operators have to handle String too. Simplest is to have run time conversions:

In pseudo-code:

```
Object rhs = stack.pop();
Object lhs = stack.pop();
TypeCasted casted = operator.typeCast(lhs, rhs);
lhs = casted.lhs;
rhs = casted.rhs;
stack.push(operator.eval(lhs, rhs));
```

The simplest type cast, i.e. for `=` would be:

```
if (lhs.getClass() != rhs.getClass() {
    if (lhs instanceof String) {
        rhs = String.valueOf(rhs);
    }
    ...
}
return new TypeCasted(lhs, rhs);
```

---

***After edit of question:***

```
        if (v1.getClass() == v2.getClass()){
           if (v1 instanceof Comparable){
               Comparable b1 = (Comparable) v1;
               Comparable b2 = (Comparable) v2;
               return b1.compareTo(b2) == 0 ? BigDecimal.ONE : BigDecimal.ZERO;
           } else {
               throw new IllegalStateException("Comparable expected instead of: "
                   + v1.getClass().getName());
           }
       } else {
```

By the way you might introduce *many* types: BigDecimal, Integer and so on, allimplement Number, which might be used as `((Number)obj).longValue()`.

Comment: I will slowly trying to do as you said. I am newbie in java so maybe i got some problems. Thanks already!

Comment: what you mean with TypeCasted casted = operator.typeCast(lhs, rhs); ? It is some library or i need to make class ?

Comment: You would need to write such a class yourself. The idea is, to do the parameter type conversion separately before the actual operator eval. And maybe share the conversion code for similar operators. You have to pick some logic: LHS determines result type, or String supercedes, or different parameter types gives an error.